# Moving files based on size with ascending order from one server to another in linux

Tags: linux, rsync, scp

How to move the files based on the size with ascending order from one server to another in Linux.

Comment: How about this: `tar -cvf - $(ls -l|sort -n -k +5|awk '{print $9}')|nc remote.host remote.port`?

Comment: thanks but we are trying with scp so if there is anyother alternative solution there?

Comment: `scp -v $(ls -l|sort -n -k +5|awk '{print $9}') you@remote.server` It can not handle files with spaces in it.

Comment: where I can specify my files path here

Comment: It works from the current directory. It copies only files (no directories, etc).